# Jest return non zero code when task is succeeded complete

Tags: javascript, jestjs

When my test failed on CI Jest return code 1
[image]
But build task succeeded complete. How to make Jest return always code 0, when test pass or failed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible to Jest return always code 0 because Jest return *code 0* when all test run/passed successfully and In your scenario your test failed and if any of the test failed then it gives you *error code 1*.So, that is the usual behavior in this scenario.
If you want to overcome from this issue kindly use any HTML reporter their are many packages in the npm. like jest-html-reporter or [jest-stare](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-stare) because of this packages you are to see which test case failed and what are the reason.

See jest issues here[(closed/open)](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues) for more details. Hope it would helpful for you